# How to find homography in OpenCV Python for overlaying images taken with different camera types?

Tags: python, opencv

I try to overlay two images which I took photograph using two different types of camera.
One is normal RGB cam, and another one is Dynamic Event sensor.

I tried to find homography in opencv using chessboard and warpPerspective.
Images taken on same distance are overlay well. But the further distance doesn't match from first distances.

I tried to find more various distance homography. But Failed.

this is simple case of my code.

```
import cv2


for path in path_list:
    rgb_img = cv2.imread()
    dvs_img = cv2.imread()

    rgb_gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    dvs_gray = cv2.cvtColor(dvs_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    rgb_corner = cv2.findChessboardCorners(rgb_gray, (8, 5(, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH)
    dvs_corner = cv2.findChessboardCorners(dvs_gray, (8, 5(, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH)

    rgb_corners = np.concatenate((rgb_corners, rgb_corner), axis=0)
    dvs_corners = np.concatenate((dvs_corners, dvs_corner), axis=0)

mtx = cv2.findHomography(rgb_corners, dvs_corners, cv2.RANSAC, 4.0)

converted_rgb = cv2.warpPerspective(rgb_img, mtx, (dvs.shape[1], dvs.shape[0]))

dst = cv2.addWeighted(convered_rgb, 0.5, dvs_img, 0.5, 0)
cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
```

The "mtx", matrix from findHomography function match perfectly whatever distance, is what I need

Comment: given that users cannot see `path_list` to reproduce the problem. Please show the error message...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You cannot generally overlay two images taken from two different cameras. It is however the case if you only apply a rotation for example (and then it's called panorama stitching). You should probably clarify what you want to do.